# Use third-party token from services such as Twitter Digits to register/sign-in user

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-identity-3, twitter-digits

Our app requires sign-in by either mobile number or Google. We are planning to Twitter Digits for mobile number authentication.

The flow of registration and authentication as I understand is as below:

1. Mobile app does rich authentication with Twitter Digits or Google Sign In (it's better user experience for the user to do rich auth instead of opening a web browser tab). Twitter Digits / Google Sign In returns Identity Token.
2. Mobile app calls IdentityServer to SignIn and presents Identity Token.
3. Identity server validates the presented Identity Token with Digits service or Google Auth Service.
4. Once verified, IdentityServer would try to find the user, if not present it will create one.
5. IdentityServer returns Access Token to the mobile app.

Now, I am looking for option to implement step #3-4. I need to create an API that receives an ID token and returns an auth token. No passwords involved.

Is there any way to generate auth token for a specific user?

I saw option to generate auth token wrapped in a cookie by calling HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(user.Subject, user.Username, props);

Another option that I am exploring is to see if I can use Extension Grants in any way.